# How to display data with Axios data requests?

Tags: javascript, electron

Hello I am following a youtube video on how to make BTC price tracker with electron and I have run into an issue. I found the solution to make it work but I would just like to be pointed in the right direction to further understand why this is the solution. I will provide my original attempt below and the correct solution.

```
    function getBTC() {

// var strr = [];

axios.get('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=BTC&tsyms=USD')
.then(function(response){
    // strr.push(response.data);
    console.log(response.data);
    // const cryptos = strr

    // price.innerHTML = '$' + cryptos.toLocalString('en');
})
.then(res => {
    // const cryptos = res.data
    const cryptos = res.data.BTC.USD
    price.innerHTML = '$'+cryptos.toLocaleString('en')
})

    }
```

here is the correct solution.

```
    function getBTC() {
    axios.get('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=BTC&tsyms=USD')
    .then(res => {
        const cryptos = res.data.BTC.USD
        price.innerHTML = '$'+cryptos.toLocaleString('en')
    })
}cryptos = res.data.BTC.USD
    price.innerHTML = '$'+cryptos.toLocaleString('en')
})
    }
```

I am able to reach the data and it displays correctly in the console, but it does not update properly in within the application window. Again I am just looking for some clarification on why the second code is working properly thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Both your solutions are not perfect, you probably have some errors you haven't noticed.

In the first solution, you forgot to `return` your value to the next `then` callback function. Because you didn't return any value in your first `then` the `res` variable in the second `then` is `undefined`. It is paramount that you `return` a value in a `then` callback, otherwise the next `then` callback does not have a value to work with. I'd suggest you read up on how [*chaining*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Chaining) works in Promises.

In the second solution your code runs properly for this segment.

```
function getBTC() {
    axios.get('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=BTC&tsyms=USD')
    .then(res => {
        const cryptos = res.data.BTC.USD
        price.innerHTML = '$'+cryptos.toLocaleString('en')
    })
}
```

Everything after that should throw an error in the console, because `res` is not available outside of the scope of the `then` method. And the code, after the example above, is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: Ah I see thank you for that. It clears it up. Also the first function was more of a test to see if I was actually getting any data. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

In the first case the first `.then()` does not return a Promise (or anything indeed), therefore the second `.then()` does not receive anything as an argument (`res` is `undefined`).

In the second case, everything is done in the first `.then()` block, where `response` is defined.

Comment: Thank you for your response! That makes perfect sense now that I think about it.

Answer (score -1):

I would think because you used a function with response parameter twice but in different forms in the first case it was a regular function in the second it was an arrow function maybe, that is where I would start looking hope this was helpful.